# Is it possible to obtain more Lanius crew?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

The only way I've found to get Lanius crew so far is to start with their ship, but if I'm not using a Lanius ship, is there a way for me to get more crew members?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is at least one random event that results in getting a Lanius crew member, even if you aren't piloting their vessel.

Having searched the database for the "Lanius" keyword, I found that there doesn't seem to be any events that guarantee a Lanius crew memeber; however, I believe that *any* event that gives a crew member of a random race may yield a Lanius crew member.

This has happened to me once thus far in my playthroughs of FTL:AE

Comment: I too received one from an event.

Comment: can you please put the name or the event type in your answer so I can keep an eye out for it?  Thanks

Comment: I suspect it happens with any event that gives randomly raced crew, such as the slaver events.  However, I will record them here as they come up in the future.

Comment: Stores in the Abandoned Sector often have Lanius for hire. Haven't seen them in any other sectors though.

Comment: In the abandoned sectors, there is at least one event in which a Lanius craft will approach and, in surprisingly good english, offer you a trade of some description. If you ask to buy their translator, what you'll get is a lanius named "translator".

Comment: I just found out that the kestrel type c starts with one as a crew member

Comment: The Engi vessel type C also starts with one as a crew member.

Answer (score 9):

Once being in the `Abandoned Sector` (which acts as a Lanius Homeworlds) you can obtain a Lanius crewmember from events that result in giving you a crewmember (random) or hire them from the shops.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to hire Lanius crew from stores in the Abandoned Sectors. I don't have proof now, but about three playthroughs ago, it happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

i just got one from quest.I chose 3rd option where you askt hem about their translation device -> they give you lanius named "translator"